# Разворачивание jenkins со слейвами через docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, docker

Задача: развернуть в докере (точнее, через docker-compose) дженкинс и обеспечить его слейвами (агентами) в том или ином виде - идеальный вариант подразумевает создание агентов в виде докер-контейнеров на лету, рабочий вариант подразумевает линковку контейнеров и автоподключение через swarm. Естественно, вся эта машинерия должна подниматься одной командой (`docker-compose up`) и переразворачиваться без особых проблем.

Здесь я столкнулся с несколькими проблемами:

1. Я не очень понимаю, как развернуть docker in docker. Концепция докера предполагает, что один контейнер - это один сервис, поэтому я не могу развернуть докер в том же контейнере, что и дженкинс. Следовательно, тут появляется еще один промежуточный контейнер, и тут я уже не очень понимаю, как должна быть организована сеть и кто к кому должен линковаться.
2. В случае использования swarm-подхода агент теребит дженкинс по полученному из api урлу. Здесь начинаются проблемы с тем, что этот урл должен свободно резолвиться из контейнера агента, как на тестовых разворачиваниях, которые идут сейчас, так и на полноценном боевом сервере с настоящим fqdn. Здесь я опять теряюсь в том, как настроить и подключить сеть внутри docker-compose. Если честно, swarm-подход мне нравится вообще.

Вопрос довольно размытый, но любая помощь поможет, пушо надоело мне без собственного CI жить.

Answer (score 1):

https://blog.docker.com/2013/09/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/
что значит нельзя?

Comment: @Sergey Kravchuk, где я написал, что нельзя?

---

Я на самом деле разобрался и прилинковал dind-контейнер, просто проект еще не готов, чтобы при закрытии вопроса дать на него ссылку.

Comment: @etki все ещё не готов?

Comment: @NickVolynkin конечно же я забил на него (